# getting win - loss counter to save in user default swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am comparing whether a user should get a win or loss in their score column. I can't get the code to store the win/loss and then add 1 on top of it every time the if statement runs. Here is my if statement, followed by where i call it in the view did load. Cant seem to figure where I'm going wrong. thanks for the help!

```
  viewDidLoad {
    let dailyWinsDefault = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dailyWinsDefault")
        winsLabel.text = "\(dailyWinsDefault)"
        print(dailyWinsDefault)

    let dailyLossDefault = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dailyLossDefault")
        lossLabel.text = "\(dailyLossDefault)"
        print(dailyLossDefault)
}


  showWinLossVC.callbackForWinLoss = { result in

            if result > 0.0 {

                self.dailyWins += 1
                UserDefaults.standard.set(self.dailyWins, forKey: "dailyWinsDefault")
                self.winsLabel.text = String(self.dailyWins)

                print(self.dailyWins)
            }

            else if result < 0.0 {

                self.dailyLosses += 1
                UserDefaults.standard.set(self.dailyLosses, forKey: "dailyLossDefault")
                self.lossLabel.text = "\(self.dailyLosses)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of mistakes

**Mistake 1:**

Seems like you are setting integer in UserDefault for key `dailyWinsDefault` using statement

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.dailyWins, forKey: "dailyWinsDefault")
```

And you expect it to return you String when you retrieve it with

```
if let dailyWinsDefault = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: dailyWinsDefault)
```

Why will it not return nil ?

use

`let dailyWinsDefault = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dailyWinsDefault")`

**Mistake 2:**

In your statement

```
if let dailyWinsDefault = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: dailyWinsDefault)
```

dont you think `dailyWinsDefault` should be in double quote as its a key and supposed to be string ?

try

`let dailyWinsDefault = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dailyWinsDefault")`

**EDIT:**

As OP has updated code and now facing a issue with his updated code and requested for help updating my answer.

Couple of issues again

**Mistake 1:**

In entire `ViewDidLoad` method u never assigned the value retried from user defaults to property `dailyWins` and `dailyLoses`

viewDidLoad {
       let dailyWinsDefault = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dailyWinsDefault")
        self.dailyWins = dailyWinsDefault //this is missing
        winsLabel.text = "(dailyWinsDefault)"
        print(dailyWinsDefault)

```
let dailyLossDefault = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dailyLossDefault")
    self.dailyLosses = dailyLossDefault //this is missing
    lossLabel.text = "\(dailyLossDefault)"
    print(dailyLossDefault)
```

}

**Mistake 2:**

Though not specific to your problem, you should always call `super.viewDidLoad` in your `viewDidLoad` unless u have a very firm reason for not doing so

That should help :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for response. i have tried that already, it gives me this error - Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Int'.. My issue is, it doesn't seem like its adding from 1 to 2 to 3 to 4. it just goes 1 to 1, to 1 again over and over. I thought the if statement tells the win counter to add upon itself every time

Comment: @coding-while-loading : How do u initialize `self.dailyWins` u should be initializing it with the value saved in UserDefault in viewDidLoad or somewhere. Post that code

Comment: " Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type" because  UserDefaults.standard.integer returns int and not Int? am updating my answer now

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I initialized dailyWins like this   dailyWins = Int(dailyWinsDefault)! in View did load- i may be wrong though. i am beginner at swift

Comment: So now in my view did load- the code looks like this         let dailyWinsDefault = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dailyWinsDefault")

            self.winsLabel.text = String(dailyWinsDefault)
            print(dailyWinsDefault)
            
        dailyWins = Int(dailyWinsDefault)

Comment: @coding-while-loading : That was the issue, no matter what you saved in your user default when you tried retrieving it in view did load u made a mistake `UserDefaults.standard.string` so it would return nil so I believe your dailyWins was initialized to 0 when declared so would always be of value 0. you would increment it in if condition n probably set it fine in user default but would make mistake while retrieving so try the solution mentioned above start with fresh installation (uninstall n reinstall) to track the value easily :)

Comment: It works perfect! Thank you very much my friend you are awesome for the help

Comment: You done need `dailyWins = Int(dailyWinsDefault)` statement `UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "dailyWinsDefault")` will return u int

Comment: @coding-while-loading : Am glad I could be of help :) Happy coding :) Please consider accepting the answer

Comment: @coding-while-loading : Thanks buddy :)

Comment: please view updated code, for some reason the counter is still becoming stuck at one again, i do not know where went wrong. thank you

Comment: @coding-while-loading : I dont see any update in your code yet

Comment: @coding-while-loading : Take a look at edited answer now

Comment: AHH ! That was exactly it! Works like a charm now! thank you, i hope to one day have the same expertise as you

Comment: @coding-while-loading : Am no expert buddy :) But am sure u will be one day :) These are the beginners mistake ull get over them soon :) Happy coding